# cyclic definitions error during IntelliJ worksheet

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have updated IntelliJ Idea Ultimate and scala plugin, it's working ok so far with sbt to build some projects.

Using a scala worksheet in REPL Interactive mode, I put in some code from a course lecture,

```scala
val rand = java.util.Random()

trait Generator[+T]:
  def generate(): T
  def map[S](f: T => S) = new Generator[S]:
    def generate() = f(Generator.this.generate())
  def flatMap[S](f: T => Generator[S]) = new Generator[S]:
    def generate() = f(Generator.this.generate()).generate()
    
val integers = new Generator[Int]:
  def generate() = rand.nextInt()

val booleans = for x <- integers yield x > 0

def single[T](x: T): Generator[T] = new Generator[T]:
  def generate() = x

def lists: Generator[List[Int]] =
  for
    isEmpty <- booleans
    list <- if isEmpty then emptyLists else nonEmptyLists // *1
  yield list

def emptyLists = single(Nil)

def nonEmptyLists =
  for
    head <- integers
    tail <- lists // *2
  yield head :: tail
```

At `*1` I got

```
4 |    list <- if isEmpty then emptyLists else nonEmptyLists
  |                            ^^^^^^^^^^
  |                            Not found: emptyLists
4 |    list <- if isEmpty then emptyLists else nonEmptyLists
  |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                                            Not found: nonEmptyLists
```

At `*2` I got

```
4 |    tail <- lists
  |            ^^^^^
  |            Not found: lists
```

Maybe some tweak to the settings I haven't found yet?

Comment: Running it in REPL mode will mean that `lists` will be evaluated first without knowing anything about `nonEmptyLists`. Try Worksheet mode instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put everything in an `object`.

This way the 2 `def`s that depends on each other will be available at the same time.

IntelliJ worksheets do not like such definitions as they are "evaluated" one by one. You cannot define 2 depending on one the other at the top-level, they need to be encapsulated.

Comment: I think this problem appears only when you use Ammonite, since it behaves like a REPL.

Comment: Is there such a choice in IntelliJ? I thought it can only behaves as a REPL indeed.

Comment: @user I wasn't able to get ammonite working with Scala 3, I tried when I ran into this problem. I got the REPL to work in sbt but something in the shell stripped newlines when I tried to copy in the code. As for IntelliJ, this version, has scala worksheets with settings: a checkbox for "interactive mode" and a drop down "Run type" with choices "REPL" and "Plain" - seems to work best with Interactive/REPL settings but I frequently have to trash results and rerun; I haven't got it to work as an actual REPL does.